# How to use sum (case ... when ... then ...) properly?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb, conditional-aggregation

I want to sum rows with a specific value as a particular column.
Earlier I did something like this:

```
SELECT date                                          AS 'Date',
   sum(CASE license_id WHEN 'a' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'a',
   sum(CASE license_id WHEN 'b' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'b',
   sum(
           CASE license_id WHEN '1' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END +
           CASE license_id WHEN '2' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END +
           CASE license_id WHEN '3' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END
       )                                                        AS 'c',
   sum(
           CASE license_id WHEN '10' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END +
           CASE license_id WHEN '11' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END +
           CASE license_id WHEN '12' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END
       )                                                        AS 'd'
FROM ...
...
```

This does exactly what I want but now I have a new scenario.
I need to sum up different temp results. The following code does NOT WORK but just to explain what I want to have:

```
SELECT date                                          AS 'Date',
   sum(CASE license_id WHEN 'b' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END) AS 'b',
   sum(    CASE license_id WHEN '1' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END +
           CASE license_id WHEN '2' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END +
           CASE license_id WHEN '3' THEN data.Amount ELSE 0 END +
           b
       )                                                        AS 'c',
FROM ...
...
```

So my questions are since this is only a part of the whole SELECT-Statement:

- Can I somehow make that `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... + CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ... + CASE ... WHEN ... THEN ...` simpler?
- Is there any possibility to achieve that I can use the temporary results in further calculations?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the table stucture, sample input data, and sample result rows? And what's that `+` used for at the end of each case?

Comment: First, you can remove the sections `ELSE 0` since it defaults to null, that is not added.

Comment: Use one case, instead of summing several ones.

Comment: Also, you can use `IN` as in `CASE license_id IN ('1', '2', '3') THEN ...`.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and you are using invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `b` is not understood -- or at best a reference to a column in the table rather than your expression.

This is a general property of SQL.  You cannot re-use a column alias in the `SELECT`, `FROM`, or `WHERE` clauses in the same query.  You have basically three options in MySQL:

- Use a subquery
- Repeat the expression
- Use a CTE

In this case, there is actually a fourth option, because rewriting the query simplifies the logic:

```
select date,
       sum(case license_id when 'b' then data.Amount else 0 end) AS b,
       sum(case when license_id in ('b', '1', '2', '3')  then data.Amount else 0 
           end) as c,
from ...
```

Notice that the form of the `case` is a little different, where a boolean conditions comes after the `when`.

Also, single quotes are not needed for column aliases.  If you want to prevent problems in your code, only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: "or at _best_ a reference to a column ...", I'd say the opposite, "or at _worst_ a reference to a column ...".

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but I fear that won't solve my problem. Is it possible to have a variable like @var = ('1', '2', '3') or something like that?

Comment: @DerKnecht . . . This (and the other answer as well) answers the question you asked.  If you have a different question, then perhaps you should ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are always testing `license_id` and always summing `data.Amount` then an `IN` condition would save you a lot of typing:

```
 SELECT
      sum(CASE license_id WHEN 'a' THEN data.Amount END) AS a,
      sum(CASE license_id WHEN 'b' THEN data.Amount END) AS b,
      sum(CASE WHEN license_id IN ('b','1','2','3') THEN data.amount END) as c
      ...
```

You don't specify which RDBMS you are using, but my bet is that if it supports `CASE` expressions, then it probably also supports `IN`.

Comment: Thanks @TheImpaler I've rid my example of the copypasta.

Comment: @TheImpaler, depends on if you want 0 or null for non-existing license_id's.

Comment: @TheImpaler, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=403db14ee74224d62766499e389f855e

Comment: @jarlh Holy guacamole. You are right. I tested your example in PostgreSQL, MariaDB, DB2, Oracle, and MySQL.